# Cast XML layout as view in android before setContentView

Tags: android, view, casting

I want to cast multiple XML layouts as views. Because of a change request I need to use a ViewSwitcher. So I have to cast the XML layout to Views before setContentView.

I always get a NullPointerException. I tried:

`view = (View) findViewById(R.id.viewgroup_id);`

`view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewgroup_id);`

`view = (View) findViewById(R.layout.xml_layout);`

`view = (View) getResources().getLayout(R.layout.xml_layout);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using LayoutInflater. Use this code inside your activity code-

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to inflate layouts for that

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)